# Building Flex/Java application in IntelliJ - HTML wrapper not writing correctly

Tags: java, apache-flex, maven-2, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build my Flex/Java web app from within IntelliJ rather than have to go to the command line to invoke the build from Maven.

Everything is working and compiling fine from IntelliJ except for the fact that the HTML wrapper file for the compiled SWF is not getting processed correctly; in that the ${values} are not replaced by the correct values during the compilation. For example **${project.version}** in the line:

```
<param name="movie" value="kata-client-${project.version}.swf" />
```

Should have been replaced by **0.1.37-SNAPSHOT**

If I simply do a build from maven on the command line then these values get replaced as expected.

I've configured IntelliJ to use the same instance of maven when building the project so this has me stumped.

I'm usually an Eclipse guy so, going through some teething pains here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like the process-resources lifecycle phase is not executed (which is where resource filtering takes place)

sometimes you need a shell open to just do

```
mvn resources:resources
```

which should be fast. you can probably call that as an external tool somehow from the IDE, but I don't know how, as I haven't used IntelliJ for many years

Sean